# TimelineJS: Change height of navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Im using the plugin TimelineJS http://timeline.verite.co and Im having a huge amount of difficulty trying to find the div(s) and the css that determine the height of the navigation slider - FireBug and the like just dont help. Just wondering on the off chance has any one achieved this before?

[image]

Comment: Could you make a live example?

Comment: Heres the one I am working on at the moment (CSS is half configured so please excuse the mess) http://www.clavecontraclave.com/hometimeline.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you have to change some css attributes and some JS code: 
You have to change

**timeline.css**
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation (line 151, *Change* attribute: **height**)
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation .timenav .time (line 212, *Change* **top**)
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation .timenav .content .era (line 205, *Add attribute* **max-height**)
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation .timenav-background (line 155,*Change* **height**)
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation .timenav-background .timenav-interval-background (line 155, *Change* **top**)
 - .vmm-timeline .navigation .timenav .content .marker .dot (line 171,*Change* **top**)

**timeline-min.js**
Here I just found out a way where you have to hardcode style!
Well, there is one value, for example **navheight**
**navheight** is the height of your *.navigation* Class **MINUS 50 PX**
In my example its 50!

So there is some code in line 32 where stands

```
}else{VMM.Lib.stop(w.flag);VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top",S)}I.start_page&&a[m].type=="start"&&VMM.Lib.visible(w.marker,!1);
```

You have to replace the `VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top",S)`-part with:

```
if(S>50){VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top","50px")}else{VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top",S)}
```

or (not tested)

```
if(S>navheight){VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top",navheight + "px")}else{VMM.Lib.css(w.flag,"top",S)}
```

I hope thats it!
Err.. and: FireBug helped me alot! ;-)